# Ado.net provider 2.0 for .C# .net provider 4.0

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using Sqlite ADO.NET provider 2.0 in my c# application .net framework 4.0.

`Question1:` Does this .dll come with a back up Database functionality?.  If the suer wants to backup, looks like I have to get the source code and write my own backup feature. 
Or is it already provided and I just need to use it?

```
Question2 :
```

I tried downloading a recent version of Sqlite ADO.NET provider(line 3.5/4.0)
from this website

```
http://www.sqlite.org/download.html/ 
sqlite-dll-win32-x64-3071300.zip
```

After attaching the dll as reference, it still says

```
 Version v2.0.50727. 
Description: ADO.NET 2.0 Data Provider for SQLite. Is this correct stable version or is there a recent one to be used.
```

Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Question 1: The ADO.NET provider isn't ***meant*** to have a backup capability.  That's something the RDBMS software should have.  ADO.NET is just a tool used to simplify communicating with the RDBMS.
 - However, SQLLite backups are documented at http://www.sqllite.org/backup.html

For #2 I don't see a question - just a statement that you got a warning from Visual Studio.  BUT based on what I'm seeing, you **will** get an error.  You're trying to use an SqlLite provider for .NET 3.5 or above, and your .NET project is set to 2.0.  Either upgrade your app to 3.5 or above, or look for an older .dll to download and use.

As a ***general rule of thumb***, in a .NET project, you can use .dll files specified for an older version of the Framework, but not .dlls specified for newer versions.

Comment: is there a recent version of ADO.net provider I could use other than 2.0 version for .Net framework is 4.0